# Python & FreeBSD: threading.currentThread().ident returns same value even in different processes

Tags: python, multithreading, freebsd

As the title says, different calls to `threading.currentThread().ident` returns 34382823872, even in different processes. (Using Python 3.1 & FreeBSD)

Is it FreeBSD's problem with python threads or not?

Comment: On a mac I get `-1601345760` for different processes. Why you think it is a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you testing this in the REPL? Or in an actual program? I ask because when I ran the below using the REPL, I got the same result, but when I ran the same as a script, the threads had different identifiers.

```
import threading

def thid():
    print threading.currentThread().ident

t1 = threading.Thread(target=thid)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=thid)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

REPL output:

```
>>> t1.start()
4301111296
>>> t2.start()
4301111296
```

Script output:

```
me@mine:~ $ python th.py 
4300935168
4302835712
```

I suspect this is expected behavior; the below is from the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.ident) docs:

> The ‘thread identifier’ of this thread or None if the thread has not been started. This is a nonzero integer. See the thread.get_ident() function. **Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created.**

Furthermore, I modified `thid` in the REPL like this:

```
>>> def thid():
...     print threading.currentThread().ident
...     sleep(10)
```

And when I called `t2.start()` within 10 seconds of calling `t1.start()`, they had different ids, but if I waited more than 10 seconds, they had the same id.

If you want to distinguish between different threads, just call `id(threading.currentThread())`. Python ids are always distinct.

Comment: I actually use Apache+mod_wsgi.

Comment: Ok, well, the same reasoning may well hold. Does the first thread exit before the second is called?

Comment: Maybe! I used thread ident to identify different threads but it looks it's not the good way. How i can distinguish between different threads?!

Comment: See the edit at the bottom of my answer. The `Thread` objects returned by `currentThread` are still distinct, so you can use `id` or something like that.